# Fastest way to insert a lot of rows in Oracle DB with Java

Tags: java, oracle

I am parsing a text to get all the words (around 6000/7000 words) and I do this on multiple files. I want to insert each word in my Oracle Database and if it already exists, it adds one to a counter. What I have done is that from my java application I call an Oracle procedure (with my word), the procedure checks if the word exists or not then insert or update the record.
The problem is that it is taking around 5 minutes for each file, is there an other way to do what I want so it is faster ?

Comment: please post some code ...

Comment: check autocommit is disabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create an in memory map of the counts in java and process all records in-memory.

So if there were 50 instances of word A your map will end up with A:50.

You can then use the

```
merge
```

oracle upsert command to either update the database records by adding the in-memory value or insert a new row with the sum.   Use oracle bulk operations to do the merges.

Comment: I have never used 'merge' before, will I have to do a prepared statement with to call 'merge' for each words in the map ?

Comment: Likely is ora specific api call for merge: so may need to cast to OraclePreparedStatement